# WaitUntil not waiting / Get HTML on WaitForSelectorAsync

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

Having two problems that I would appreciate some advise on.  Have used puppeteer in the past in node, but for some reason, running into a problem on the sharp version.

Basically I'm crawling a webpage with a WaitUntil set to  WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle0, the longest wait period.  In my node code, this runs and loads my website correctly, but in the C# version, I get the page without angular loaded.  From the best I can tell it is not waiting and returning the initial Load state.  Below is my code.

```
        if (BROWSER == null)
        {
            await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);

            BROWSER = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = true,
                Args = new string[] { "--no-sandbox", "--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas", "--disable-gpu", "--proxy-server='direct://'", "--proxy-bypass-list=*" }
            });
        }

        if (page == null)
        {
            page = await BROWSER.NewPageAsync();
            await page.SetUserAgentAsync("PScraper-SiteCrawler");
            await page.SetViewportAsync(new ViewPortOptions() { Width = 1024, Height = 842 });

            var response = await page.GoToAsync(url, new NavigationOptions() { Referer = "PScraper-SiteCrawler", Timeout = timeoutMilliseconds, WaitUntil = new[] { WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle0 } });
        }
```

Timeout is set to 30 seconds, or 30,000 milliseconds.  I then get the html of the page doing

```
await reponse.TextAsync()
```

My second question is unrelated, but likely simpler to solve.  One route I was considering was using the page.WaitForSelectorAsync() method.  This appears to wait until the content I'm looking for is loaded, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the entire html of the page after this is done from the ElementHandle return.

Would appreciate some help here, tried a couple routes and haven't been able to figure out whats causing the difference between the node and C# code.

Comment: Can you repro that with any URL you can share here?

Comment: https://github.com/nicholasconfer/SamplePuppeteerSharp  try https://angular.io as the url querystring.  It should give completed html of page, but is showing state before angular html is loaded into DOM.

Comment: worth noting that I realize the setup of browser and page in the code is not ideal for multiple requests.  Working on some other code that essentially sets up a queue to make the fetches more efficienct, and this was just a quick copy over of the basic code to fetch a url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem.  The issue was how I was getting the html of the page.

I was using...

```
await reponse.TextAsync()
```

Apparently, this gets me only the initial response.  When I changed my html get to the following line of code everything worked as expected.

```
await page.GetContentAsync()
```